# How to Create a Class for Every Asyncio Connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Just think that I have a game and I am creating Client class for every connection. And Client Class stores user preferences (like selected country). And when user is disconnected from the game class deletes. I need to do something like this. My code:

```
import asyncio
import logging
import sys

SERVER_ADDRESS = ('localhost', 56346)

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(name)s: %(message)s',
    stream=sys.stderr,
)
log = logging.getLogger('main')

event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

class Client():
    def __init__(this):
        this.something = ''

class Server(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        self.address = transport.get_extra_info('peername')
        self.log = logging.getLogger(
            'EchoServer_{}_{}'.format(*self.address)
        )
        self.log.debug('connection accepted')
    def data_received(self, data):
        self.log.debug('received {!r}'.format(data))
        self.transport.write(data)
        self.log.debug('sent {!r}'.format(data))
    def connection_lost(self, error):
        if error:
            self.log.error('ERROR: {}'.format(error))
        else:
            self.log.debug('closing')
        super().connection_lost(error)

factory = event_loop.create_server(Server, *SERVER_ADDRESS)
server = event_loop.run_until_complete(factory)
log.debug('starting up on {} port {}'.format(*SERVER_ADDRESS))
# Enter the event loop permanently to handle all connections.
try:
    event_loop.run_forever()
finally:
    log.debug('closing server')
    server.close()
    event_loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
    log.debug('closing event loop')
    event_loop.close()
```

Comment: Do you want a *class* or an *object*?

Comment: I want to have a Client class which stores user datas. Each user is going to have a Client class. If I make print(client.Username) they are going to see their own Usernames.

Comment: Yes, but your terminology is off. The class is the code and the object is an instance of running that code. The thing you want to create is apparently an object, not a class (i.e. not new code. That would have been kind of interesting, actually!)

Comment: Creating a `Client` object is simply `object = Client(parmeters...)` but I can't tell offhand where in this wall of code you want that to happen. Maybe [edit] your question to actually *ask* a question, and reduce the code to a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `Server` as the `protocol_factory` to `create_server`, which means a new `Server` instance will be created for every client. (A better name for this class would be something like `ClientHandle`.)

The logical place to instantiate the client is inside `connection_made`:

```
self.client = Client()
```

Depending on the protocol you are implementing, the client will presumably be required to authorize themselves. You will fill the attributes of the client as they arrive in your `data_received` method. Also note that you are not creating a new `Client` *class* for a client, you are creating a new `Client` *instance*.

Implementing the communication is much easier with the streams-based API, which provides a coroutine mapping to the callbacks. For example:

```py
class Client:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.reader = self.writer = None

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self._clients = set()

    async def new_client(self, reader, writer):
        addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
        writer.write(f'hello client from {addr}; please state your name\n'
                     .encode('utf-8'))
        name = (await reader.readline()).decode('utf-8').rstrip('\n')
        client = Client(name)
        client.reader = reader
        client.writer = writer
        writer.write(f'{name}, you are now represented as {client}\n'
                     .encode('utf-8'))
        # Add the client to the set of known clients. This would also
        # be the place to notify the application of the new client.
        # This coroutine could continue running and communicate
        # with the client without blocking the app.
        self._clients.add(client)

app = App()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(
    asyncio.start_server(app.new_client, *SERVER_ADDRESS, loop=loop))

# serve the requests until someone calls loop.quit()
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: What is self._clients (and is it necessary?) and when user is disconnected from the game how Client instance will be deleted?

Comment: @EgehanAVCU It's a set of all connected clients and it's not strictly necessary, but you'll likely need such a collection in _some_ form. You can find out that a client is dead by checking `at_eof` on the reader stream. There is probably a way to add a callback to be invoked as soon as that happens.